# How to set the same index twice (once inside an each loop and another outside of it)?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, it runs on click:

```
  var obj = $scope,
      i = 0

  circle.append("text")
    .text(i++)

  function getXY (obj, prop) {
    obj[prop] = []
    d3.selectAll('g')
      .each(function () {
        var c = d3.select(this)
        var cX = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[0]
        var cY = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[1]
        obj[prop].push({ index: i++, x: cX, y: cY })
      })
  }
```

The first `i++` is always 0 and the second one works correctly. It goes `1`, `2`, `3`, etc

How to make the first one also increase it's value like the second one?

Comment: `circle.append("text").text(i++)` display only one value, so which value you want to show?

Comment: Go look up the difference between `i++` and `++i`.

Comment: i++; is post increment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34896887/5678086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the below declaration of your variables outside the `click` event handler. That will fix the issue.

```
var obj = $scope,i = 0;
```

Because for each click, i was being reset to 0.